# How to install tkinter for python 3.9 on xubuntu 20.04?

Tags: xubuntu, python

I have just installed python 3.9, but it doesn't come with tkinter apparently.  When I try

```
sudo apt install python3.9-tk
```

I get the message

```
Note, selecting 'python3-tk' instead of 'python3.9-tk'
python3-tk is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

Python 3.8 is the system default.  How can I get tkinter for python 3.9?

**UPDATES**

As suggested by ubfan1, I tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure python3-tk
```

but I got the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py'
```

I made a tkinter directory and added empty files for each file that dpkg complained about.  (Every file in the tkinter directory, so far as I can see.)  Then `dpkg-reconfigure` ran with no errors, so I tried

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

again, and I got the same message as above, telling me that the newest package was already installed.  I was able to import tkinter in python 3.9, by `root=tkinter.Tk()` failed.  On inspection, all the files in `/usr/lib/python/` were still empty, so I decided to copy all the scripts from python 3.8.  This time, python told me `no module named _tkinter`.  I found a module named

```
_tkinter.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

in `/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload` and I copied it into `/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload` replacing the "38" in the name with "39".

This seems to have worked, in the sense that tkinter runs under python 3.9, but I need hardly say that I don't feel entirely comfortable with this.  What's going to happen when I upgrade to python 3.10.?

Comment: What do you need that's not in the /lib/python3.9/tkinter location?

Comment: @ubfan1 There's no such directory on my system

Comment: It's in the python3-tk package, along with the 3.8 version.

Comment: @ubfan1 Are you saying I should just copy it into the python3.9 library?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-tk and the /lib/python3.9/tkinter directory will be created with contents.

Comment: @ubfan1 That's the first thing I tried, but it tells me that it's already installed and doesn't do anything.  Do I need to somehow change the default python to 3.9?  I know if I just manually point python3 to python3.9 the system gets messed up.

Comment: What are you trying to do that gives an error?  python3-tk supplies both the 3.8 and 3.9 tkinter directories under their respective /lib/python3.x directories.  Contents the usual dialog.py filedialog.py, messagebox.py, colorchooser.py, etc.  Of course, you still need tcl and tk to be installed.

Comment: @ubfan1 There must be something wrong on my machine.  I have a python3.9 directory in both /lib and /usr/lib.  Neither of them has tkinter.  Both lib directories contain tcltk.  tkinter works perfectly under python 3.8.  I don't know how to troubleshoot it.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled python 3.9 (several times) and then tried `sudo apt install python3-tk` and `sudo apt install python3.9-tk` but I just get a message telling me it's already installed.

Comment: Looks like the pythons were reinstalled after the python3-tk package, wiping out the parts of python3-tk that were in the python3.x directories. Try dpkg-reconfigure python3-tk   (note, not python3.9-tk, there is no such package).  If the reconfigure complains, try a --force

Comment: @ubfan1 dpkg-reconfigure gives `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py'`  I tried uninstalling and re-installing python3.9 yet again, but it didn't help.

Comment: Ouch, the cleanup fighting with the package manager to get to a consistent state is much harder than the actual reinstall -- many answers here for that problem.  Caused by deleting files in a package, (mostly kernel), then finding purge on the package falls on its face.  One way I found is to give it whatever it wants, sudo touch <missing file> or mkdir if needed. Even a 0 length file will do, and get beyond the problem of "package already installed" but files deleted.  Add information to your original posting, comments tend to get deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you installed a new python version that newer than the one in your system or repository, or you installed it to a location different than `usr/lib/python3.x` (in my case, `usr/local/lib/python3.9.4`), installing the package
`python3-tk` will not help you directly.

To solve this problem, firstly you need to search for the right `python3-tk.*deb` file. One place to do it is [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=python3-tk). For my case, I use python3.9.4, so the newest file I can find is [python3-tk_3.9.2-1_amd64.deb](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/python3-tk_3.9.2-1_amd64.deb.html)

As long as it matches the second minor version number, it will work just fine.

Then, after you downloaded that deb file, extract it with any Archive Manager.
Continue to extract the `data.tar.xz` inside.

Then, navigate to `data/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/`, you will see there is a pre-built shared lib file `_tkinter.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Finally, all you have to do is to copy that file to the correct folder of your
python installation. In my case, it is `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'm sure I'll find this useful the next time I upgrade python.

Comment: Thanks! it works like a charm!

Comment: A direct installation of that deb file should also work the same way !?